# In between HTML content not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

When i try to add an variable content in between HTML its not displaying after JSON call,But if i initialise with dummy value its showing. Here my code

```
   {
    xtype: 'panel',
    height:'115px',
    html:['<div style="margin:0px;background:#fff;" >'+
           '<table style="margin:0px;padding:0px;height:40px;" width="100%" >'+
           '<tr><td style="padding:2px;width:40%;"><span><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{userImage}" height="100px" width="100px"/>'+
           '</span></td>'+
            '<td align="center" style="padding-left:2px ;width:60%;"><font color="black">'+App.gvars.fusername+'</font><br><p style="background-color:blue;"><font color="white">ITEMS COUNT : 155</font></p>'+
            '</td></tr></table></div>'].join(),
    }
```

App.gvars.fusername content is not displaying, if i initialise with some temprory value App.gvars.fusername content="Test", its working! whats the problem in this code?please help me

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the panel gets created before `App.gvars.fusername` gets set from the JSON response.  You'll need to use `tpl` instead of `html` so that you can update the content after you get the data you need.

```
{
   xtype: 'panel',
   height: '115px',
   itemId: 'my-panel',
   tpl: [
      //...
      '<font color="black">{fusername}</font>
      //...
   ]
}
```

Then, when you get your JSON response, you can update the `tpl`.

```
panel.update({
   fusername: App.gvars.fusername
}):
```